# JQuery calculate shipping based on item details, only 2 possible choices, how would you go about it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 Shipping options,

If the item is **A5** and is only 1 item then shipping price is **£0.67p**
If the item is **A4** and is only 1 item then shipping price is **£0.87p**

**Otherwise the shipping price is £0.97p**, (If more then 1, any size, any amount).

Now In my view I have the following table row with the selectors:

```
<table id="tbl_basket">
<tr class="tbl_row">
    <td>Image</td> <!-- First Cell (Not required for example) -->
    <td class="tbl_basket_description"><!-- Second Cell (Note: .size) -->
        Print : <span class="basket_item_specific type">Landscape</span><br/> 
        Size  : <span class="basket_item_specific size">A4</span><br/>
        Colour: <span class="basket_item_specific color">White</span><br/>
    </td>

    <td class="price_unit">1.99</td>

    <td align="center">
    <input type="text" name="qty" value="1"/>
    </td>

    <td class="total_item_price">1.99</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I need to calculate which shipping price is required based on the above.
I need some Jquery Code to say this:

```
if (only 1 .tbl_row exists) // If only 1 row exists (How do I do this?)
{
     var size = $('.size').html();
     if(size == 'A5')
        $('.shipping_price').html('£0.67') // Show Shipping Price (A5)
     elseif(size == 'A4'){
        $('.shipping_price').html('£0.87') // Show Shipping Price (A4)
     }
}
else  // More then 1 row exists, so the price will be £0.97
{
    $('.shipping_price').html('£0.87') // Show Shipping Price (A4)
}
```

So basically, thats what I want to do, most of the logic is there, but how would I test to see if only 1 .tbl_row exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ($(".tbl_row").length == 1)
{
...
}
```

Comment: Yup Thanks!, so simple, I thought that would return the length of string or something.